# Uploadify onCancel event

Tags: asp.net, postback, delete-file, uploadify

I am using Uploadify plugin for asp.net web appication.

I want to let user delete an uploaded file. For this, I used onCancel event of Uploadify.

But, the problem is, if the page refreshes/postbacks, the FileUpload queue of Uploadify gets clear automatically.
How do I keep the queue-items as it is on Postbacks?

How do I delete files on server after they are automatically uploaded?
Do I need to write code in Upload.ashx or in codeBehind file of the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store file upload status in database on file upload completion, at onCancel event just check (create handler with ajax call) whether there is already uploaded item stored, if yes then delete it.

There is no way to keep track of uploaded item once postback happen, all you need to store data in some sort of states (session, cookie) or in database.

Comment: Looks like a lot of work.
Even if I store file names in states, a postback clears the FileUpload queue and there is no way I could draw the Queuelist again.
I cannot find any suitable example implementing this.
I think, I have to remove the cancel button to disable file delete option.
Thanks for the input though.

Comment: Such implementation require lots of structuring, better is to implement a way to i: upload files, ii: once uploaded keep files in draft or temp, iii: once user click on file submit button, change all uploaded file status as published. add a way in admin to delete all draft or temp upload files which is uploaded few hours before.